# PayPal API Get shipping address by transaction ID

Tags: .net, api, paypal

Does PayPal provide API to retrieve shipping address by transaction ID?

p.s. I am using /n software PayPal Integrator for .Net.

Thanks

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to answer it. You should specify the PayPal API you're using on the site, as the requests supported differ from API to API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [GetTransactionDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_SOAP/) to obtain all of the information about the order including the shipping address.